# Drupal : editing content theme broken?

Tags: drupal-8

When editing content in Drupal theme is broken ?
What could be the reason.
Urls like :

```
http://www.test1.com/admin/content
http://www.test1.com/node/add/article
http://www.test1.com/node/add/page
http://www.test1.com/admin/structure/block
```

are all broken.. but others like :

```
http://www.test1.com/admin/structure
http://www.test1.com/admin/appearance
```

are OK.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Changed the Admin theme and it seem OK so far.
Seems current Drupal 8 ships with broken theme or something !!